# Xcode: Linked Frameworks vs Other Frameworks

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Coming from a C background, what would "Linked Frameworks" and "Other Frameworks" mean?

Having a look at my build target, I see that Linked Frameworks are in fact linked (dynamically, I presume - how would static linking work?)

What are "Other Frameworks" for then?

To test, I used the NSString class which is defined by Foundation in a file. Foundation is in Other Frameworks and is not being linked with the target.

Alas, compilation finished without warnings and the executable ran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're just groups in the Groups & Files hierarchy.  They don't have any more meaning than that.

The frameworks referenced in Other Frameworks are just there so you can twist them down to see their headers easily, because (for example) Cocoa.framework doesn't itself actually contain the physical Foundation.framework, AppKit.framework and CoreData.framework directories.  It just acts as if it does when linking, for developer convenience.

Comment: So "Linked Frameworks" might be thought of as "Direct Framework Dependencies", while "Other Frameworks" would be "Transitive Framework Dependencies", correct?

Comment: Maybe. But remember that they're just groups for organizing the references to the frameworks. The actual linkage behavior is handled entirely by the Link Frameworks & Libraries build phase of the target.

Comment: Is it true that you can only use frameworks in Link Binary with Libraries build phase of the target, if you specify them in the Frameworks group (or any subgroup)?

Comment: No, that is not at all true. It doesn’t matter where in a project the file reference pointing to a framework is, you can use that reference in the Link Binary with Libraries build phase.